# GLMM with scaled variable: do I need to back-transform?

Tags: data-transformation, glmm, back-transformation, scale-parameter

I am fitting a GLMM to powerline collision data for a bird species- using distance to seasonal water, habitat and the presence/absence of line markers as predictors. Incident is a binary response (50 presences vs. 1282 absences).

To get the model to converge I had to scale and center the only continuous variable (distance to seasonal water). I had though that scaling and centering would not affect interpretation of the results, given that it is giving you log odds.
However I notice the estimates and SE for this variable change if I scale only (without centering). So my question is, do I need to back transform in order to interpret the results? Or can I interpret as is? And how would I go about this?

Since this variable is the most significant, I want to be able to make practical recommendations on actual distances. For example, I'd like to compare the odds of powerline collision for powerlines 0-10km from seasonal water vs. powerlines greater than 10km.

```
Scaled and centered data:

WC_BC$dist_seasonal_scaled <- scale(WC_BC$Dist_seasonal, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

WCBCmodelscaled3 <- glmer(Incident ~ 
                            dist_seasonal_scaled+Habitat_grouped+Markers+
                            (1|Transectname)+
                            (1|MonthYear_Grouped)
                          , data = WC_BC, family = "binomial")


summary (WCBCmodelscaled3)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Incident ~ dist_seasonal_scaled + Habitat_grouped + Markers +      (1 | Transectname) + (1 | MonthYear_Grouped)
   Data: WC_BC

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   360.6    397.0   -173.3    346.6     1325 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.1511 -0.1753 -0.1122 -0.0623 10.0602 

Random effects:
 Groups            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Transectname      (Intercept) 2.2766   1.5088  
 MonthYear_Grouped (Intercept) 0.2443   0.4943  
Number of obs: 1332, groups:  Transectname, 38; MonthYear_Grouped, 6

Fixed effects:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                            -4.5010     0.5251  -8.572  < 2e-16 
***
dist_seasonal_scaled                   -1.5862     0.3815  -4.158 3.21e-05 ***
Habitat_groupedfynbos_woodland_shrubs  -1.5125     0.6354  -2.380  0.01729 *  
Habitat_groupedWaterbody_bare          -0.8158     0.8577  -0.951  0.34153    
Markersyes                              1.5727     0.4794   3.280  0.00104 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) dst_s_ Hbt___ Hbt_W_
dst_ssnl_sc  0.483                     
Hbtt_grpd__ -0.033  0.054              
Hbtt_grpdW_  0.049  0.122  0.069       
Markersyes  -0.245  0.011 -0.026 -0.091

Scaled data (no centering):

WC_BC$dist_seasonal_scaledonly <- scale(WC_BC$Dist_seasonal, center = FALSE, scale = TRUE)
> WCBCmodelscaled3_1 <- glmer(Incident ~ 
+                             dist_seasonal_scaledonly+Habitat_grouped+Markers+
+                             (1|Transectname)+
+                             (1|MonthYear_Grouped)
+                           , data = WC_BC, family = "binomial")
> 
> 
> summary (WCBCmodelscaled3_1)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Incident ~ dist_seasonal_scaledonly + Habitat_grouped + Markers +      (1 | Transectname) + (1 | MonthYear_Grouped)
   Data: WC_BC

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   360.6    397.0   -173.3    346.6     1325 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.1511 -0.1753 -0.1122 -0.0623 10.0603 

Random effects:
 Groups            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Transectname      (Intercept) 2.2767   1.5089  
 MonthYear_Grouped (Intercept) 0.2443   0.4942  
Number of obs: 1332, groups:  Transectname, 38; MonthYear_Grouped, 6

Fixed effects:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                            -2.6921     0.4943  -5.447 5.13e-08 ***
dist_seasonal_scaledonly               -2.4064     0.5787  -4.158 3.21e-05 ***
Habitat_groupedfynbos_woodland_shrubs  -1.5125     0.6354  -2.380  0.01729 *  
Habitat_groupedWaterbody_bare          -0.8158     0.8577  -0.951  0.34156    
Markersyes                              1.5727     0.4794   3.280  0.00104 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) dst_s_ Hbt___ Hbt_W_
dst_ssnl_sc -0.367                     
Hbtt_grpd__ -0.083  0.054              
Hbtt_grpdW_ -0.055  0.122  0.069       
Markersyes  -0.270  0.011 -0.026 -0.091
```